# Selenium: how to write if condition when there is no element for some xpath

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Below is the code and question:

```
if(result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[4]/span/a/i")).getText().equals("Lightning Deal"))
```

After we search any product on Amazon, we can also see the "Lighting Deal" option on some products. Now here I am trying to check if the lighting deal option is present or not. If it is present then condition is true and everything is okay. But if there is no lighting deal, then this gives the error `NoSuchElementException` because then `div[4]/span/a/i` doesn't exist. This `div[4]/span/a/i` comes into life only when there is some lighting deal.

Please suggest me how to write this if condition.

Complete Code:

```
//All the products after searching in List
List<WebElement> resultsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id, 'result_')]"));

for(WebElement result:resultsList)
{
System.out.println("Name of the product:"+result.findElement(By.tagName("h2")).getText());

System.out.println("Brand: "+result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]")).getText());

    if(result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[4]/span/a/i")).getText().equals("Lightning Deal"))
    {
        String sp =result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[5]/div[1]/a/span[2]")).getText();
        System.out.println("Selling Price: "+sp);       
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Selling Price:"+result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[4]/div[1]/a/span[2]")).getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the element is present on page before getting text

```
 for(WebElement result:resultsList)
 {
 System.out.println("Name of the 
 product:"+result.findElement(By.tagName("h2")).getText());

 System.out.println("Brand: "+result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-
 item-container']/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]")).getText());

if(result.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-
container']/div[4]/span/a/i")).size() != 0
&& result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-
container']/div[4]/span/a/i")).getText().equals("Lightning Deal"))
{
  String sp =result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-
 container']/div[5]/div[1]/a/span[2]")).getText();
  System.out.println("Selling Price: "+sp);       
} 
else
{
    System.out.println("Selling Price:"+result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
[@class='s-item-container']/div[4]/div[1]/a/span[2]")).getText());
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do

```
List<WebElement> deals = result.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[4]/span/a/i"));
if(deals.size() > 0)
{
    if(deals.get(0).getText().equals("Lightning Deal"))
    {
        String sp =result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[5]/div[1]/a/span[2]")).getText();
        System.out.println("Selling Price: "+sp);       
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Selling Price:"+result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[4]/div[1]/a/span[2]")).getText());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the if Statement in Try catch block

Enclose your `if` condition in `try` block . So if your element is there then you will be able to do your action in `if` condition.

If there is no such xpath then it will throw exception which will be handle under `catch` block so just write you `else` part under `catch` block

Refer Below code:

```
//All the products after searching in List
List<WebElement> resultsList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id, 'result_')]"));

for(WebElement result:resultsList)
{
    System.out.println("Name of the product:"+result.findElement(By.tagName("h2")).getText());

    System.out.println("Brand: "+result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]")).getText());

    try
    {
            if(result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[4]/span/a/i")).getText().equals("Lightning Deal"))
            {
                String sp =result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[5]/div[1]/a/span[2]")).getText();
                System.out.println("Selling Price: "+sp);       
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)

    {
            System.out.println("Selling Price:"+result.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='s-item-container']/div[4]/div[1]/a/span[2]")).getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my favorite hack. Basically the question is regarding, to check the element availability or not in the given page. **findByElements** method comes to action now. Below is the code.

```
if(driver.findElements(ByXpath("XPATH_HERE")).size>0)
{
  //DO THE STUFF YOU NEED TO DO IF THE ELEMENT EXISTS
}
```

The statements inside the if block will be executed only there exists the element defined otherwise not. Hope this helps you.

Thanks.